# UK - wife declined for credit card due to pregnancy

Tags: united-kingdom, credit-card, maternity-leave

My wife was recently declined for a credit card based solely on the fact she is 6 months pregnant and will soon be on maternity leave.

The scenario details are as follows:

Application was made in person in a pre-booked appointment. The process was undertaken by a trainee. Various details were entered into the system including salary (>£30k), savings (>10k) and current debt (<5k). Then various questions were asked including "will your financial circumstances change within the next two years?". My wife answered yes and explained she is due to go on maternity leave soon. At this point a "computer says no" message appeared and she was told that this was the end of the appointment. My wife expressed surprise and the trainee consulted other members of staff who confirmed that the change in circumstances resulting from maternity meant that she could not obtain a card at this time.

My wife has a completely clean history and was understandably surprised. She has since applied (successfully) to another organisation. During the application this other organisation told her that, since she is on maternity leave and not losing her job, she should answer no in response to the question about a change in circumstances. Further, they offered to contact the bank and ask why she had been declined - The bank responded that she had been declined for a variety of reasons and categorically denied that pregnancy was in any way a factor in their decision (this is clearly a lie). Thus not only was the application likely declined erroneously but her credit score has been impacted.

Obviously we will be withdrawing all accounts from this bank and will not use them again. We have put in a direct complaint with the bank but don't believe that they will take this seriously.

**The question**: is there something more punitive that we can do and/or is there any way to undo the (minor) damage to credit score?

**Update**: the bank's complaint service "investigated" the complaint but decided that the action was justified and repeated their own fictitious sequence of events, essentially ignoring our complaint. We are now escalating the matter to the Financial Ombudsman.

Comment: just to clarify, when you say "clean history" do you mean that she has a credit history which has no negatives on it or that her credit report has no items on it? This may make a huge difference

Comment: She has a credit history with multiple previous credit cards, phone contracts and a credit agreement to purchase a ring. I believe she also paid bills at her previous address. I don't think she has ever been declined before or missed a payment.

Comment: thanks for the clarification; the maternity leave, which reads as financial instability, could just have been adding to the lack of a history to tip them to not extend credit. That would be fair enough, this seems wrong.

Comment: The question as asked appears fine, i.e. on topic, but no need to name the bank. It quickly changes the tone of the question to 'complaint/rant' vs request for sound advice.

Comment: "is there any way to undo the (minor) damage to credit score?" It doesn't seem that her credit score (in the sense of the score reported by credit agencies) was affected, just that a lender looked at her income in *addition* to her score. What percentage of her current income will she be receiving during leave?

Comment: Another organisation could see that she was declined. Presumably that would result in a lower credit score? Maternity pay is the NHS package spread over 1 year. I believe that this equates to 30-50% of her normal pay but it is tricky to calculate.

Comment: Out of curiousity, is it normal to do an in-person application for a credit card in the UK?  I've never heard of such a thing in the US.

Comment: "Another organisation could see that she was declined." Is that definitely the way it works in the UK? Only the hard pull would be on the report in the US.

Comment: The reduction in income can, I suppose, be legitimately taken into account, but at least in the USA, denying a credit card only on the basis of pregnancy is unlawful.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I'm pretty sure it isn't legal here either. The question is what to do about it. One option would be to complain to the Financial Ombudsman Service but I'm not sure if they would be the appropriate authority. My gut feeling is that they mostly exist to resolve monetary disputes.

Comment: I know nothing about the Ombudsman, but I suggest looking for a feminist organization, like Planned Parenthood here, because the will have ideas.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus - are you guessing or do you know that Planned Parenthood will advocate in the kind of situation?

Comment: I can find PP taking on a workplace discrimination case. So at least some similar cases interest them. https://www.plannedparenthoodaction.org/blog/our-message-supreme-court-dont-allow-pregnancy-discrimination-workplace

Comment: Why do you think it would be illegal to decline a credit care based on lower income? Why are you looking for something "punitive" against a reasonable action?

Comment: @Acccumulation see my comment on jadoti's answer - it's not a reasonable action in the UK, it's illegal.

Comment: OP, I would definitely suggest the Financial Ombudsman, although you do have to go through the bank's complaints procedure first. If you don't get satisfaction with that then the FO is the next step.

Comment: @Vicky there is nothing illegal about declining based on a announced upcoming change in financial situation, OPs wife will be earning less on maternity leave fact, if she no longer meets the criteria for the loan they decline. The pregnancy really isn't a factor in the decision, and that is what the financial ombudsman would tell you

Comment: Essentially, if you tell a creditor "today I make X but in a few months I will only be making a fraction of that" then *they're perfectly allowed* to decide to not lend you money, regardless of the reason why your income is dropping. This is not discrimination. It's acting on a fact that clearly impacts your ability to pay a loan. Discrimination is *unfair or unequal* treatment. If an otherwise-identical pregnant woman and a non-pregnant woman were both about to lose half their income for a year, and the bank only lent to the non-pregnant woman, *that* would be discrimination.

Comment: @dwizum - that isn't how the law works here in the UK. You could equally well say that if a pregnant and non-pregnant woman were both planning to take a 1-year leave of absence then you as an employer have the right to terminate their jobs.....but we both know that that isn't how it works (fair or not).... it is entirely normal for organisations to be required (by law) to discriminate in favour of people with protected characteristics such as pregnancy.

Comment: Unless the bank is her employer, this question isn't about terminating her job, is it? I'm talking about discrimination in lending, not employment. Lenders are allowed to make decisions based on income changes, regardless of why the income is changing.

Comment: Morally, the discrimination is identical (I assumed you were making a moral argument when you mentioned fairness). If you are confident that this is legally not counted as discrimination then I'd be pleased to read that as an answer.

Comment: Banks aren't in the business of morals. They're in the business of lending. They need to rely on data that makes estimations on someone's ability to repay a loan. It's not a moral decision, whether we like it or not. I did consider writing an answer but I think you already have two which indicate the same point I'm trying to make - pregnancy or not, if someone discloses that they're about to have a 50 - 70% paycut, a bank may legitimately choose to make a lending decision based on that.

Comment: In terms of discrimination, the requirement on the bank is to prove that they're treating otherwise-similar individuals the same. In other words, if they have pregnant candidate A and non-pregnant candidate B, (or white candidate A and hispanic candidate B, and so on) and they're identical in terms of credit history, DTI, and other factors, then the bank simply has to show that they treated them similarly. Discrimination would only come into play if people like A and B consistently received different lending decisions at a given FI.

Comment: Adding to @dwizum 's comment, The Bank cannot lend to you if you do not meet affordability criteria, they are not legally allowed to enter you into a loan if there is a high risk you cannot afford it, this obviously requires them to make an assessment of your income.

Comment: @dwizum are you commenting specifically about UK law, and if so have you considered the concept of "indirect discrimination"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not in the UK, but just a matter of observation:

> My wife was recently declined for a credit card based **solely on the fact she is 6 months pregnant** and will soon be on maternity leave.

No, your wife was declined because her financial situation was presented as it would be negatively affected.

She likely would have been declined if she said she was going on vacation for 6 months and her financial situation would also be negatively affected. In such case, she wouldn't be getting declined "solely on the fact that she's taking a vacation".

The bank is going to give you an official reason for declining you (or at least they do here in the states), and they sound like they already took an official stance when your next bank called them for their reasoning. Just because you got the impression it was because of a protected reason like pregnancy doesn't make it so.

And, and here's really the main point, **even if** you're 100% convinced it was because she was pregnant and solely because she was pregnant, you'd then have to prove it. Bank will fall back on any subjective reason to decline her. In cases like this you'd likely have to prove the bank has a history of such actions, or catch a bank official on tape telling you it was solely because of her pregnancy, or something extreme to that nature.

Best advice, recognize the bank is awful (in your experience) and move on with life. Move your money, don't do business with them, which it sounds like you're already doing. :)

Comment: That's not how the law works in the UK. Pregnancy is a protected status, unlike going on vacation, so you can't be discriminated against because of it or because of the consequences of it.

Comment: @Vicky I think the answer made pretty clear that pregnancy is a protected status in theory, but in this practical situation that doesn't matter because OP can not prove that it was discrimination due to pregnancy and the bank has plausible deniability. I am not that familiar with how UK law works either, but until now I assumed that it follows the regular principle of law which states that the burden of proof lies with the accuser, not the defendant. Am I wrong about that?

Comment: @Vicky your income is not a protected characteristic, if she is taking a pay cut to go on maternity leave they can decide to decline or accept based on the expected change of income. They cant decline for being pregnant, they can decline if your income is going to become too low due to maternity leave. mortgages are the same and ive recently done a course on things like that for work.

Comment: @J.Doe if they want to discriminate based on income then shouldn't they have asked for details? Maternity packages vary enormously.

Comment: @Vicky Cite? Do you have something that *specifically* addresses this issue, or are you simply arguing that it follows from pregnancy being a protected class? Just because something results from a protected characteristic, does not mean that it's illegal to discriminate based on it.

Comment: Also, are you confident that the income can be legally considered to be reduced? Maternity rules in other areas essentially force maternity leave to be treated identically to full time employment. e.g. national insurance.

Comment: @P.Hopkinson the income source has to be treated as identical not the amount and depending on the bank just saying "yes" to the yes no question might get you declined.

Comment: @P.Hopkinson also the amount will be considered different by law for national insurance, tax etc. you will be paying less tax because it is a lower amount, they can't discriminate on the fact its maternity pay. but they can and will take the amount into account.

Comment: @Acccumulation the latter. However, by the OP's statement, they didn't ask what her income would be when she was on mat leave,just ended the process as soon as she said she would be on mat leave. Some employers continue to pay full pay, or 90% of full pay, through the whole mat leave.

Comment: @P.Hopkinson I think that you are right to go to the FO. You might also get somewhere asking this question on law.SE.

Comment: @Vicky I get it's a protected status, the point was the OP deduced it was because of her pregnancy.  I'm just saying that's going to be a hard case to prove based on one instance, especially one side of one instance, as I'm sure the bank will have a different reason for declining her.

Comment: @Philipp 1.  There is (almost) no UK law; it's either Scottish law or England-and-Wales law.  The law in New York is a better guide to the law in E&W than the law in Scotland.  2.  It is technically true that the claimant has to prove their claim; but this is a civil case and they only have to do it "on the balance of probabilities".  If the wife gave evidence that the interview proceed as in the OP, then they would probably succeed on the balance of probabilities.

Answer (score 6):

The pregnancy is a red herring as such, they have not declined you to do with the pregnancy, they have declined due to a expected decrease in income that takes you below the threshold required to get the loan.

protected characteristics like pregnancy can't be used to discriminate, but your income is not a protected characteristic , and the protection doesn't extend to the decrease in income coming from maternity leave.

If you applied for the loan with your wife's expected income from maternity leave from the start and not said anything about the pregnancy, you would of most likely still been declined.

There is no punitive action to take, because there has been no discrimination that has taken place. Just because you don't like the result doesn't make it discrimination.